# Running Perl debugger twice

Tags: perl

I have a case where I invoke the Perl debugger twice. For example, `progA.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

system("perl -d progB.pl");
```

and `progB.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
$DB::single=1;
print "Hello\n";
```

Then I run `progA.pl` like:

```
$ perl -d progA.pl
```

This does not work very well. On my system (Ubuntu 14.04, and Perl version 5.18), I get some errors from the debugger. For example:

> ### Forked, but do not know how to create a new TTY. #########   Since two debuggers fight for the same TTY, input is severely
>
> entangled.
>
> I know how to switch the output to a different window in xterms,
>   OS/2   consoles, and Mac OS X Terminal.app only.  For a manual switch,
>   put the name   of the created TTY in $DB::fork_TTY, or define a
>   function   DB::get_fork_TTY() returning this.
>
> On UNIX-like systems one can get the name of a TTY for the given
>   window   by typing tty, and disconnect the shell from TTY by sleep
>   1000000.

It also tries to open a new terminal window, with title `Dauther Perl debugger` but the new terminal only show the error `sh: 1: 3: Bad file descriptor`.

How can these problems be avoided? I just want the debugger to work as normal.

Comment: Why are you using system() to start Perl in debug mode?

Comment: I'm not on a linux box so can't test, but something like this should work: `system('xterm -e perl -d progB.pl');`

Answer (score 1):

Use 'do' instead of 'system'

```
perl -d progA.pl
# will stop after your $DB::single = 1 
# line in progB.pl

perldoc -f do

    do EXPR Uses the value of EXPR as a filename and executes the contents
            of the file as a Perl script.

                   do 'stat.pl';

               is just like

                   eval `cat stat.pl`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, because I don't understand the bigger picture of what you are trying to do.

But if you use a different debugger like [Devel::Trepan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan) at the outset, then things may work:

```
$ trepan.pl progA.pl 
-- main::(progA.pl:4 @0x21282c8)
system("perl -d progB.pl");
(trepanpl): s
-- main::(progB.pl:3 @0x7042a8)
$DB::single=1;
(trepanpl): s
-- main::(progB.pl:4 @0x878be8)
print "Hello\n";
(trepanpl): s
Hello
Debugged program terminated.  Use 'q' to quit or 'R' to restart.
(trepanpl): quit
trepan.pl: That's all, folks...
Debugged program terminated.  Use 'q' to quit or 'R' to restart 
(trepanpl) quit
trepan.pl: That's all, folks...
```

The `(trepanpl)` prompt after the "program terminated" message is a bit odd. But all it means here is that progB.pl is finished. After quitting that, as I did above, if you had another Perl statement after your *system()* command, then debugger show that rather give the second "finished" message.

Another feature of *Devel::Trepan* is that you can do nested debugging from inside that debugger with its [debug command](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan::CmdProcessor::Command::Debug). Here is an example of that:

```
trepan.pl progA.pl 
-- main::(progA.pl:4 @0x10612c8)
system("perl -d progB.pl");
set auto eval is on.
(trepanpl): debug system("perl -d progB.pl")
-- main::((eval 1437)[/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Devel/Trepan/DB/../../../Devel/Trepan/DB/Eval.pm:129] remapped /tmp/HSXy.pl:6 @0x51f13e0)
system("perl -d progB.pl")
((trepanpl)): s
-- main::(progB.pl:3 @0x9382a8)
$DB::single=1;
(trepanpl): s
-- main::(progB.pl:4 @0xaacbe8)
print "Hello\n";
(trepanpl): s
Hello
Debugged program terminated.  Use 'q' to quit or 'R' to restart.
(trepanpl): quit
trepan.pl: That's all, folks...
$DB::D[0] = 0
Leaving nested debug level 1
-- main::(progA.pl:4 @0x10612c8)
system("perl -d progB.pl");
(trepanpl):
```